# Multiple tables from different pages into one data frame

Tags: r

I am trying to extract the tables from different pages into one data frame. However, I am only able to get it as a list and I am unable to convert to one table. Could you please help me out?

Code we are using so far:

```
Tables_recent <- lapply(paste0("http://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/stats/index.html?class=3;home_or_away=1;home_or_away=2;home_or_away=3;page=",
                            1:50,
                            ";template=results;type=batting"),
                        function(url){
                          url %>% read_html() %>%
                            html_nodes(xpath= '//*[@id="ciHomeContentlhs"]/div[3]/table[3]') %>%
                            html_table()
                        })
```

Answer (score 1):

It's nested within a list, so you need to get out the first element, and also remove entries that are "No records available to match this query"

```
library(dplyr)
library(textreadr)
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

LINK = "http://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/stats/index.html?class=3;home_or_away=1;home_or_away=2;home_or_away=3;page="
Tables_recent <- lapply(paste0(LINK, 1:50,";template=results;type=batting"), function(url){ 
       url %>% read_html() %>% 
       html_nodes(xpath= '//*[@id="ciHomeContentlhs"]/div[3]/table[3]') %>%
       html_table() 
})
```

we check the number of columns for each page entry:

```
> sapply(Tables_recent,function(i)ncol(i[[1]]))
 [1] 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16
[26] 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
```

Those with ncol == 1 are empty:

```
> Tables_recent[[50]]
[[1]]
                                        X1
1 No records available to match this query
```

We loop through non-empty and then rbind

```
wh = which(sapply(Tables_recent,function(i)ncol(i[[1]]))==16)

Table = do.call(rbind,lapply(Tables_recent[wh],"[[",1))
head(Table)
                  Player      Span Mat Inns NO Runs   HS   Ave   BF     SR 100
1      RG Sharma (INDIA) 2007-2019 101   93 14 2539  118 32.13 1843 137.76   4
2        V Kohli (INDIA) 2010-2019  72   67 18 2450  90*    50 1811 135.28   0
3        MJ Guptill (NZ) 2009-2019  83   80  7 2436  105 33.36 1810 134.58   2
4 Shoaib Malik (ICC/PAK) 2006-2019 111  104 30 2263   75 30.58 1824 124.06   0
5       BB McCullum (NZ) 2005-2015  71   70 10 2140  123 35.66 1571 136.21   2
6        DA Warner (AUS) 2009-2019  76   76  8 2079 100* 30.57 1476 140.85   1
  50 0  4s  6s   
1 18 6 225 115 NA
2 22 2 235  58 NA
3 15 2 215 113 NA
4  7 1 186  61 NA
5 13 3 199  91 NA
6 15 5 203  86 NA
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have is a list. try

```
do.call(rbind,lapply(Tables_recent,function(x){x<-as.data.frame(x); if(length(x)>1)x}))
```

or you could do

```
do.call(rbind,Filter(function(x)length(x)>1,lapply(Tables_recent,as.data.frame)))
```